# Match strings based on sound/homophones in python?

Tags: python, matching

I am working on a python program that, at one step, takes an input (string), and matches it to songs/artists in a users library. I'm having some difficulty, however, figuring out how to match when the input/library contains numbers/special characters. For example, take the group "All-4-One". In my library it might be listed exactly like that. I need to match this to ANY of the following inputs:

- all-4-one (of course)
- all 4 one (no dashes)
- all 4 1 (all numbers)
- all four one (all spelled out)
- all for one (phonetic spelling of "four")

Or, really, any other combination that *sounds* the same. The reasoning for this is that the input comes from a speech recognition system, so the user speaking "4" could be recognized as "for", "four" or "4". I'd imagine that Alexa/Siri/Google all do things like this (since you can ask them to play songs/artists), but I want to implement this in Python. How can I do this?

Comment: This is not a trivial task.

Comment: You probably want a library implementing the soundex algorithm, or similar - a quick Google finds a couple.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah, no kidding. I certainly didn't mean to imply that it was, if I did :-) I'm just pretty sure it's *possible* since the big names in speech recognition apparently do it :-)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, I'll look for that. Knowing *what* to look for is quite helpful :)

Comment: So I managed to work this out using a combination of normalization (via the num2words library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words/0.5.6) to match, for example, four and 4, and the fuzzywuzzy library (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy) to handle phonetic matching (i.e. four vs for). I'd post this as an answer, but apparently I can't because the question has been marked as "too broad"???? Perhaps not trivial, but I can't see how it's not specific. Oh well.

Comment: @ibrewster post your problem and solution to medium :)

Answer (score 1):

for each name normalize string first: remove symbols like '-', ''' or '\', substitute phoneticks what you want.

```
all-4-1 becomes ["all", "for" ,"one"]
all-four-1 becomes ["all", "for" ,"one"]
crappy\"new"\1 becomes ["crappy", "nju", "one"]
```

then match full list, or just some words, like occurence "for", "one" means the likelyhood of 66% there is this group.

to substitute create a dictionary like:
`dict { "4":"for", "four": for", 1:"one", new:"nju"}` etc...
or create a file like:
subs.txt:
4 for
four for
1 one
...
and read in into dict.
as you create this, cou could link it to me since i also have a project where i might need phonetick substitutions :D

is haste i have created the very alfa version (modified a little bit further) :

```
    '''
Created on Jan 29, 2018

@author: noob
'''
import re

path = "X:/Programming/workspaceEclipse/PyTutorials/"

sounds = open(path + "txt/sounds.txt", 'r')


def toDict(file):
    dict = {}
    for line in file:
        key, val = line.strip().split(" ")
        dict[key] = val
    return dict


d = toDict(sounds)

print("dict:" , d)

str1 = r"be4-the-storm"
str2 = r"u2/best/hits"
str3 = r"A.B.B.A- what4"
str4 = r"all-4-one"
str5 = r"all four one"
str6 = r"all 4 1"
str7 = r"w8-4ever"

strs = [str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7]



def toNorma(words,dict):
    ret= []
    for word in words:
        w = word.lower()
        ret.append(dict.get(w ,w ))
    return ret    

def toNormaStr(str):
    return toNorma(re.findall(r'w8|m8|[0-9]|[a-zA-Z]+', str), d)
#exceptions like w8,m8 come first in the regex

def show(str):
    print(str + ":" ,toNormaStr(str) )

for str in strs:
    show(str)
```

where 
sounds.txt is:

```
    a ei
b bi
c si
d di
f ef
g gi
h ejch
i aj
j dzhej
k kej
l el
m em
n en
o ou
p pi
q kju
r a
s es
t ti
u ju
v vi
w dabelju
x eks
y waj
z zet
1 wan
2 to
3 thri
4 for
5 faiw
6 siks
7 seven
8 ejt
8 ajt
9 najn
10 ten
one wan
two to
three thri
four for
five faiw
six siks
eight ejt
nine najn
w8 vejt
m8 majt
what vot
```

Having the output like:

```
     be4-the-storm: ['be', 'for', 'the', 'storm']
u2/best/hits: ['ju', 'to', 'best', 'hits']
A.B.B.A- what4: ['ei', 'bi', 'bi', 'ei', 'vot', 'for']
all-4-one: ['all', 'for', 'wan']
all four one: ['all', 'for', 'wan']
all 4 1: ['all', 'for', 'wan']
w8-4ever: ['vejt', 'for', 'ever']
```

Comment: Wouldn't such a dictionary be (theoretically at least) infinitely large? The numbers, for example, go on for quite a while. I could, of course, start with some obvious ones, and expand, but unless I had a list of every *possible* song and artist, from which I could develop normalizations, I would think it would be quite difficult to create/maintain. Perhaps for personal use only...

Comment: yeah it will be quite a bit if you include all english words but not extrem large, there will be like 100k most frequently used words.
there is digits to distinguish in english:
from 0-20, then 20,30...100, then only "thousand", "million", etc.
For creating a song list, just have big archive of albums .mp3 files,
read names and create dictionary of tokens.
Ahh, further you can include fusage of sounds like 4ever => forever:
just distinguish complex token where are digit + letters and replace digit

Comment: here are some https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:List_of_dialect-independent_homophones